# Styling a button in the Form::submit

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-5, materialize

In the standard method a submit button in my form is as

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light center signup_btn" type="submit">
    Submit
    <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>
</button>
```

I am using materialize.css
Now how can i achieve the same UI using the FormBuilder of the Illuminate\Html package

```
{!! Form::submit('Submit',['class' => 'btn waves-effect waves-light center signup_btn' ]) !!}
```

But this does not render the button correctly. The "waves-effect" class causes the rest of the classes be applied to `<i>` tag. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So someone helped me over the [gitter forum](https://gitter.im/laravel/laravel)...

Though this might not be the correct way solution, but this definitely solves the problem.

```
{!! Form::button('<span class="mdi-content-send right"></span> Submit', array('class'=>'btn waves-effect waves-light center signup_btn', 'type'=>'submit')) !!}
```

Some padding needs to be applied to the span, so that submit and the icon are a bit apart.